# yii query buid error in adyen callback class

Tags: php, yii, callback

So I have the following scenario:

A user recharges his account via Adyen API and when the payment is processed I have a ProcessOrder method that receives the callback and does the following:

```
public function ProcessOrder($order)
{
    //some order processing
    $order_total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('sum(`amount`) as total')
                    ->from('`order_table`')
                    ->where('`uid` = ' . $order->user->id)
                    ->queryRow(); 
//send email with data
}
```

And I know the $order_total is failing but I don't know why...

I want to check logs but I don't know where they are (I'm new to this project) and I am trying to send me a email with the result. I cannot var_dump() the result and then die() because the class method is called via Adyen callback...

So basically my question is:

Where are the logs in a yii app **OR**

Why is the query failing? :-?

**More Info**

- This class is the Order Module file under protected.
- The var `$order->user->id` has the correct value, I checked this with email :D
- I also tried `foreach($order_total as $row) { //send result }`  and nothing... It's like the system does not have access to perform query s in that part

Please ask in comments if more information is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)) This is stupid...

So I figured out why this does NOT work and the problem is this:

order_table and uid MUST NOT HAVE **apostrophes** **``**! Without them, the query executes and everything works fine.

And yii app logs are in **runtime** folder :)

(And for those of you new to Yii and what to know how to call something from a query like this, the value is is $order_total['total'])*